# How to exclude classes from an OpenCover report

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, opencover, reportgenerator

In generating coverage reports with OpenCover (and then generating an HTML report with ReportGenerator) for an MSTest suite, I am trying to exclude framework generated classes. In particular, classes generated under the project's namespace by a service reference.

The command I am using to generate the XML files looks like:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:MyProject.Tests.dll" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:MyContainer" -output:coverage.xml -mergebyhash -filter:-*.AWebService.*
```

I have also tried to exclude by file:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:MyProject.Tests.dll" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:MyContainer" -output:coverage.xml -mergebyhash  -excludebyfile:*Reference.cs
```

but the service reference classes still show up in the XML file.

Is there a way to exclude only those specific classes generated by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you forgot assembly part in filter arg, try with this:

```
-filter:"+[*]* -[*]*.AWebService.*"
```