# How can I escape a PowerShell reserved word?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell to compose a command to execute `OpenCover` which has a flag [`-filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467122/1226568)

However it turns out that [`Filter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847868.aspx) is one of the reserved words in PowerShell.

The command that I generate (which runs fine under `CMD`) is:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -output:Coverage.xml -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[*]*.Test*" -target:nunit-console.exe -targetargs:"Test.dll /config:Release /noshadow /nologo /labels"
```

But when I run it inside PowerShell I get an error:

```
Incorrect Arguments: The argument [*]*.Test* is not recognised
```

Answer (score 3):

This have nothing to do with `filter` being reserved word in PowerShell. The problem in how PowerShell pass parameters to native application. Your command line will be passed as:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -output:Coverage.xml -register:user "-filter:"+[*]* -[*]*.Test*"" -target:nunit-console.exe "-targetargs:"Test.dll /config:Release /noshadow /nologo /labels""
```

Some extra quotes, added by PowerShell, cause that wrong command line will be passed to native application.

First thing you can try, is to change command line to following:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -output:Coverage.xml -register:user "-filter:+[*]* -[*]*.Test*" -target:nunit-console.exe "-targetargs:Test.dll /config:Release /noshadow /nologo /labels"
```

In that case, no extra quotes will be added by PowerShell, and possible that `OpenCover.Console.exe` can recognize your command.

If that does not help, than you could use `Start-Process` cmdlet, it never add any extra qoutes:

```
Start-Process OpenCover.Console.exe '-output:Coverage.xml -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[*]*.Test*" -target:nunit-console.exe -targetargs:"Test.dll /config:Release /noshadow /nologo /labels"' -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Awesome! `Start-Process` Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the "about_Escape_Characters" section on PowerShell technet? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847755.aspx

STOP-PARSING SYMBOL

When calling other programs, you can use the stop-parsing symbol (--%) to prevent Windows PowerShell from generating errors or misinterpreting program arguments. The stop-parsing symbol is an alternative to using escape characters in program calls. It is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

For example, the following command uses the stop-parsing symbol in an Icacls command:

```
icacls X:\VMS --% /grant Dom\HVAdmin:(CI)(OI)F
```

For more information about the stop-parsing symbol, see about_Parsing.

Comment: Hi Chris, I can't use `Verbatim` as I am on PowerShell 2.0